# Apex trigger with Helper Class not working

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I'm very new to apex coding. I was informed that the proper way of creating trigger is to create a trigger then call apex class methods. Is that right?

I tried it on my end with a very simple trigger but I can't make it work.
Basically, what I want is that when I create Account, it will automatically create a Contact under the Account with Account is equal to Account id and contact last name is equal to account last name.

Attached is my trigger and class.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include any code on this exchange as *text*, not images. Text is significantly more accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method does not return anything.

change the signature to

```
public List<Contact> createCont(List<Account> AccRec){
   ....

   try{
       insert newCont_lst;
       return newCont_lst;
   }....

}
```

You will also need to change your `insertCont` to a list of contacts and not a list of accounts as you currently have it

Comment: And preferably move the Contact list within the method's scope to avoid unexpected surprises.